# Capturing random numeric values

Tags: c#

I've got text file:

```
Pool 53-12-74 up 123,55
Estimate,00: 237-123 not case, send up
Tech 123-45-6
Over head 12-22-27-8 beat
Pool 230-000 get up
Blink 123-90-88-3 up
...
```

and etc. where X is random number. I need to capture all values (with "-"  symbol) which contains six digits. I do not have any idea how to do this with one regular expressions.

Comment: So what do you need to capture? The strings `xxx-xxx` or do you actually need the numeric value? If you file is structured like that you don't even need a regular expression. You could simply `Split` each line on the space and take the second element. Have you tried anything?

Comment: No, file hasn't strong structure.

Comment: So what *is* the structure? With the examples you give, a simple split would work. Define your problem first and you are half way to solving it. At the moment it seems like you do not have a good definition of the problem.

Comment: Even with your edits, there are no cases where a simple split wouldn't work. `var numStr = line.Split(' ')[1];`

Comment: Yeah, yeah, it captures all with "head" and other obsolete values. I need values with next wildcards: xx-xx-xx or xxx-xxx or xxx-xx-x

Comment: Now that you've edited the question, then yes, that would no longer work. But it is still a simple regular expression to match digits plus some number of `-`.

Comment: Well I was working on an answer. But if you aren't willing to help yourself, I don't know why I should bother.

Comment: And what about lines like `Over head 12-22-27-8 beat`? That value contains 7 digits. Do you want just the first 6, or do you not want that value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try *regular expressions* and *Linq*:

```
String source = 
  "a 123-456 up\nb 12-34-56 up\nc 987-55-4 beat";

String pattern = "[0-9]+(-?[0-9]+)*";

// [123-456, 12-34-56, 987-55-4]
String[] matches = Regex.Matches(source, pattern)
  .OfType<Match>()
  .Select(match => match.Value)
  .Where(match => match.Count(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9') == 6) // exactly 6 digits
  .ToArray(); // optionally, if you want matches as an array
```

Comment: @kate: that's why I've added *Linq* filter: `.Where(match => match.Count(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9') == 6)`

Comment: That's work. How about regular expression without Linq?

Answer (score 1):

As per given data, Simple `Split` function may solve your problem

```
String[] s = File.ReadAllLines("FilePath");
foreach (string item in s)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item.Split(' ')[1]); 
}
```

Comment: And what? There is "head" in output and all numbers bu t I need values which contains six digits (wildcard xxx-xxx or xxx-xx-x or xx-xx-xx).

Comment: what is `Over head`?, if head comes in second position you need to manually handle this situation and access the next index in split function to get Number